# Anomalous scaling in GeoRegionValuePlot when using non-default color scheme

Tags: color, geography

I found this plot online,

[image: plot]

and thought "I bet I could do that with a one-liner using `GeoRegionValuePlot`".  But then it turns out that you are much better off using a log-scale because you have recognized `CountryData[]` entities like [Macau](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Macau) that really wreck the color bar.  How exactly to implement a log scale in this kind of plot is one matter I think I could work out, although I reckon the legend will have to be hand-built.

But I noticed on some of my tests that Greenland seemed to have an insane population density, and I was able to condense it down to a simple example:

```
GeoRegionValuePlot[{Entity["Country", "Greenland"] -> 1, 
  Entity["Country", "Brazil"] -> 5.5, 
  Entity["Country", "Afghanistan"] -> 20}]
GeoRegionValuePlot[{Entity["Country", "Greenland"] -> 1, 
  Entity["Country", "Brazil"] -> 5.5, 
  Entity["Country", "Afghanistan"] -> 20}, 
 ColorFunction -> ColorData["BlueGreenYellow"]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

As you can see, the coloring works just fine when using the automatic color function, but when you supply a built-in color function (the same one that is used in the [documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GeoRegionValuePlot.html)) it doesn't work.  In the second plot, Greenland should be the darkest color.

This gives the same problem in version 10.1 and 10.4, but version 10.0 gives the [correct plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R2u2E.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is definitely a bug in the color function rescaling of `GeoRegionValuePlot`.  Here is an even simpler instance of the problem,

```
{GeoRegionValuePlot[{Entity["Country", "Greenland"] -> 1, 
   Entity["Country", "Brazil"] -> 5., 
   Entity["Country", "Afghanistan"] -> 20}, 
  ColorFunction -> "BlueGreenYellow"],
 GeoRegionValuePlot[{Entity["Country", "Greenland"] -> 0, 
   Entity["Country", "Brazil"] -> 5., 
   Entity["Country", "Afghanistan"] -> 20}, 
  ColorFunction -> "BlueGreenYellow"]}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

So if we look at the actual color function used in the version that works,

```
Trace[GeoRegionValuePlot[{Entity["Country", "Greenland"] -> 0, 
     Entity["Country", "Brazil"] -> 5., 
     Entity["Country", "Afghanistan"] -> 20}, 
    ColorFunction -> "BlueGreenYellow"],
   HoldPattern[ColorFunction -> _Function], TraceInternal -> True] // 
  Flatten // First
```

[image]

it says that if the value is `Missing[TooLow]` or is 0., then use the dark blue color, and if it is `Missing[TooHigh]` to use the yellow color.

Now look at the `Trace` output when I change the 0 above to a 1,

[image]

Now the color for the `TooLow` or 0 is set as yellow, so whichever country has the lowest value will instead default to the highest-valued color.  As noted in the question, this does not occur when the default color function, aptly named `` System`GeoPlotsDump`defaultGeoRegionValuePlotColorFunction ``, is used.

A workaround is to turn off `ColorFunctionScaling`,

```
GeoRegionValuePlot[{Entity["Country", "Greenland"] -> 1, 
  Entity["Country", "Brazil"] -> 5., 
  Entity["Country", "Afghanistan"] -> 20}, 
 ColorFunction -> ColorData[{"BlueGreenYellow", {1, 20}}], 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]